# Representing semantical relations with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, linguistics

What is the best way to draw those two semantical relations with TikZ? I’ve seen it in a paper describing relations within wordnets.

[image: synonym]

[image: hypernym]

Comment: If you would like that, you can make an exact copy using tikz, then define a command to make it easier to use. Is it an one-off illustration or do you plan to make extensive use of such drawings? If you do not need exactly the same result, you can also try mindmapping library as in http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/

Comment: I plan using it just once for a report, but I think eventually I’ll want to use it in an article. The result doesn't have to be exactly the same. However, the size of the circles and the dashes connecting them are meaningful. For instance, checkmate and xeque-mate have the same circle size and the same dash size because they share a direct synonym relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try with

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{normal}=[circle,text=white,fill=black]
\tikzstyle{superset}=[normal,inner sep=1em]


\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [column sep=3em,row sep=1em]
    {
    \node (a) [normal] {Subset}; & \node (b) [superset] {Superset}; \\
    \node (a caption) {\parbox{6em}{\textbf{\{Caption\}}\\Lorem ipsum}}; & \node (b caption) {\parbox{6em}{\textbf{\{Caption\}}\\Lorem ipsum}};\\
    };
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \fill (a.center) -- (b.north east) -- (b.south east) -- (a.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [column sep=3em,row sep=1em]
    {
    \node (c) [normal] {One set}; & \node (d) [normal] {One set}; \\
    \node (c caption) {\parbox{6em}{\textbf{\{Caption\}}\\Lorem ipsum}}; & \node (d caption) {\parbox{6em}{\textbf{\{Caption\}}\\Lorem ipsum}};\\
    };
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw [line width=0.8em] (c.center) -- (d.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But you have to be careful and use `minimum width` or `text width` key-values when needed to achieve the sizes you really need.

Result:

[image: Sets]

Comment: What if I wanted to put a caption above node b? Is that possible?

Comment: All the nodes are contained inside a matrix, so you can just rearrange them however you see fit -- instead of a matrix a & b \\ a caption & b caption you could create a matrix [empty] & b caption \\ a & b \\ a caption & [empty]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `mindmap` library; a little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,mindmap}

\newcommand\MyAnn[4]{%
  \node [annotation,below] (#1) at (#2.south) {\textbf{ \{#3\}}\\#4};
}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{concept color=red!50,%
    every annotation/.style={text width=4cm,text badly centered,font=\large}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
  \node [concept] (vodka) {WN.Pr}
    child[grow=left] {node[concept] (caipi) {WN.Br}};
  \MyAnn{fn}{vodka}{vodka}{text text text text.};
  \MyAnn{sn}{caipi}{caipirosca}{text text text text.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={minimum size=3.5cm,font=\large},mindmap]
  \node [concept] (chek) {WN.Br} 
    child[grow=right] {node[concept] (xeque) {WN.Pr}};
  \MyAnn{fn}{chek}{chekmate}{text text text text.};
  \MyAnn{sn}{xeque}{xeque-mate}{text text text text.};
  \end{scope}
  \node [style=double arrow,draw,fill=black,scale=0.5] at ($(fn)+(2.4,0.25)$) {dblarrow};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I've changed the code to include the second example.

[image]

Comment: I think I’ll go with that by now. How do I control font size with TikZ? Or should I use regular LaTeX commands, such as \small and \normalsize? Thank you!

Comment: @Rafael Beraldo: of course, you can use the standard font switches; I've added a second example code showing how to change the annotations style.